# SetKwInOut error

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I'm having some problems with the algorithm2e package. Here's the code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Tree merge algorithm\label{alg:merge}}
  \SetKwData{H}{H}\SetKwData{M}{M}\SetKwData{C}{C}\SetKwData{R}{R}
  \SetKwData{SH}{SH}\SetKwData{SM}{SM}\SetKwData{SC}{SC}\SetKwData{SR}{SR}
  \SetKwData{N}{N}\SetKwData{E}{E}\SetKwData{X}{X}
  \SetKwInput{KOutput}{output}
  \SetKwInput{KInput}{input}
  \KInput{local tree object (\H) and remote tree object (\M)}
  \KInput{common ancestor object (\C)}
  \KOutput{resulting tree object (\R)}
  ...
```

This code works properly, as expected. If, however, I replace \SetKwInput with \SetKwInOut (which is the formatting I want to use), I get the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.163   \SetKwInOut{KOutput}{output}

?
```

I have other algorithms in the same file that work properly and don't give me this error. What is the problem here? The package is used as:

```
\usepackage[dotocloa,boxed,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a full MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[printonlyused,nohyperlinks]{acronym}
\usepackage[dotocloa,boxed,algochapter]{algorithm2e} % describe algorithms

\title{Book Title}

\author{Jonatan Schroeder}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Implementation Details}
\label{ch:implementation}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Tree merge algorithm\label{alg:merge}}
  \SetKwData{H}{H}\SetKwData{M}{M}\SetKwData{C}{C}\SetKwData{R}{R}
  \SetKwInOut{KOutput}{output}
  \SetKwInOut{KInput}{input}
  \KInput{local tree object (\H)}
  \KInput{remote tree object (\M)}
  \KInput{common ancestor object (\C)}
  \KOutput{resulting tree object (\R)}

  \Return \H\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I make a small document around the sample code, I get no error. Please, show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with the problem.

Comment: Trying to come up with an MWE I noticed that, if I change the keyword for M to something else (e.g., MM) the code works. Apparently the problem is with my choice of variable name. Does this make any sense? I basically replaced `\SetKwData{M}{M}` with `\SetKwData{MM}{M}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
\SetKwData{M}{M}
```

the `algorithm2e` package defines an internal macro named `\@M`, without any check this is already defined. It happens that `\@M` is a *very* important internal command of LaTeX, which stands for the number 10000.

I think that this approach by `algorithm2e` is disputable. Not only an internal macro can be overwritten without any warning, but also user's macros can be overwritten.

Use a different naming scheme. Also `\H` is taken, for instance; you'd get a puzzling error message in case in your algorithm you use the name “Erdős” (assuming you use UTF-8), because this would be translated into `Erd\H{o}s`.

The error you get

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
```

is exactly because a macro that's being expanded uses `\@M` as alias for 10000, but it has been redefined to mean something completely different.